# PHP non eof-recordset returning empty values

Tags: php, recordset

i'm having a strange problem with php + recordsets. 
my code:

```
    $rc = mysql_query("select * from myTable",$db);
    if (!$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rc))
    {
        $eof=true;
    }else{
        echo "there is data!<br>";
        $rs = mysql_fetch_array($rc);
        echo $rs[id];
        echo $rs[txt];
    }
```

the strange thing - the query is correct - it's echoing "there is data" but when echoing the actual field values returns empty strings .. :(

any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `else` block, you are re-fetching some data from the database, using `mysql_fetch_array()`.

But a first row has already been fetched earlier, by `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.

So, basically :

- In the `if`'s condition, you are **fetching a first row**
- If it succeed, you enter the `else` block

  - where you try to **fetch a second row**
  - and using the returned *(or not)* data, without testing the success of that second fetch.

**You should probably do only one fetch** -- using either `mysql_fetch_assoc` or `mysql_fetch_array` -- but not two.

Answer (score 2):

you already fetched data, use `mysql_num_rows()` instead

```
$rc = mysql_query("select * from myTable",$db);
if (mysql_num_rows($rc))
{
    echo "there is data!<br>";
    $rs = mysql_fetch_array($rc);
    echo $rs[id];
    echo $rs[txt];

}else{
    $eof=true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Be consistent in your use of if mysql_fetch_assoc($rc)...

```
$rs = mysql_fetch_array($rc);
```

will return an enumerated array, so $rs['id'] doesn't exist only $rs[0], $rs[1], etc.

Use

```
$rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($rc);
```

to return an associative array with $rs['id']

Your first test also fetches and discards a row

And quote the indexes in $rs: $rs['id'] rather than $rs[id]